# Air compressor first use - plug needs to be replaced?

Tags: compressor, air-compressor, air

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem.

My brother bought an air compressor recently and found this note. What does that mean, which plug should we replace? This yellow one with two holes in it? Does anyone know the name of that part, what should I search for? Googling for "air compressor replace plug" gives no relevant results.

Thanks.

[image: Text]

Comment: Have you read the instruction manual? I'd imagine that it will tell you how to remove that plug (the most likely candidate for removal), and what, exactly, to replace it with. Barring that, providing the make/model of the compressor would probably be helpful, as neither of the compressors I've purchased had a similar tag and warning. It would also be helpful to indicate if this is a gas or electric compressor - the cooling fins in the picture indicate gas. Please [edit] this additional info into your post to make it easy for everyone to find.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about small appliance servicing.

Comment: It's a tool, not an appliance, but yes... RTFM (which is almost certainly available online if you don't have one).

Comment: OTOH, I asked about repairing my air compressor (in chat) and was told that it was more of a "larger appliance" which was considered on-topic. I can see closing because of failure to read the manual, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it could be answered by reading the manual.

Comment: Or taking our [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Found this on the orange store site.  It's a manual for a compressor (probably not yours):

> On the top front of the compressor you will find a white plastic
> shipping plug inserted into the Oil Filler Hole. Remove the shipping
> plug and replace it by pressing the red Oil Filler Plug (in parts bag)
> into the Oil Filler Hole.

I hate to RTFM you, but sometimes it's really important.